# how to pass null value if the KeyAttribute is not available in the json file ( gettting Key Error in python )

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have below case , where i need to capture lenght of the group. 
If the key -- 'EMP' is available then it should go for next line of code and if  doesnot exist then how to get some static value ..?

As i dont have 'EMP' in one of the source json file i am getting KeyError.

```
for j in range(len(json_file['entities'][i]['data']['attr']['EMP']['group'])):
    for key in json_file['entities'][i]['data']['attr']['EMP']['group'][j].keys():
        try:
            temp[key] = json_file['entities'][i]['data']['attributes']['EMP']['group'][j][key]['values'][0]['value']
        except:
            temp[key] = None
```

How to get "None" or Null value if the Key is not available

Comment: Please properly format the question. The code formatting should be on the JSON, not the rest of the text. Also, your JSON seems to be invalid.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply .JSON file is correct only , I just given you the sample format ..